# Android spinner onItemSelected Listener cannot see outside values

Tags: android, spinner

I have an `onItemSelectedListener` for my Spinner in my main activity. I assign the listener to the spinner object in the `onCreate` Method.

The activity class has a member variable `int iCurrentSelection`. But no matter what I set `iCurrentSelection` to anywhere in the activity, it is always null in the `onItemSelected` Method. So the boolean `changed` is always `true` even if nothing has changed.

I do not understand why! Somebody please enlighten me :-)

Here is my listener class:

```
OnItemSelectedListener oisl = new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {

        boolean changed = iCurrentSelection != arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
        stopTracks();
        if(changed){
                iCurrentSelection = arg0.getSelectedItemPostion();
                initTracks(actSpeed);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
}
```

Comment: debug your code..it cannot be null..and why do u need arg0.getSelectedItemPosition() as onItemSelected provides you the current selected position in arg2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The activity class has a member variable "int iCurrentSelection". But
>   no matter what I set iCurrentSelection to anywhere in the activity, it
>   is always null

In Java an int value would never be Null , i don't think so the problem is there! maybe the return of arg0.getSelectedItemPosition() is Null! so comparing an integer value with a Null object would return Null!

Comment: It was nice of you and i'm delightful for your comment,thx ;)

Comment: thank you for your comments, guys. the point is, that the onitemselected method is called every time the activity gets redrawn (like on orientation change). in my listener, i do some calculations that stress the cpu a lot. these calculations only need to be done if the value in the spinner has actually changed. so i need a variable to store the previous value in. then every time i the listener method gets called, i just want to check if the value has changed. if so, i need to do the calculations. if not, i just want to skip that.